# Integral $I =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried using trigonometric substitution like

> $x= \sin(\theta)$

then applied the substitution

> $t=\pi/2 - x$

to get two same integrals and sum them

but now I'm stuck with

> $$2I = \int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\ln(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))}{\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}dx$$

any help please?

Comment: The integral is supposed to be from $0$ to $1$ right?

Comment: yes, I typed wrong, let me fix